# git for-each-ref does not match the actual number of tags

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm following this instruction to try to migrate an existing svn repository to git. 
https://john.albin.net/git/convert-subversion-to-git

I cloned the repository using the command

```
git svn clone https://urltorepository.com/svn/repos-itservices/apps --no-metadata --authors-file=authors.txt --stdlayout testing
```

When I do `git for-each-ref` i get following:

```
f98b1954059631270b44ed3037d3d08127ab051a commit refs/remotes/tags/RE.15.03.00.00
181a447b465c34857c1091b06173d30f467c9941 commit refs/remotes/tags/RE.15.03.00.01
cfca76149b8f79749ef0e978b3628fdcf43955d0 commit refs/remotes/tags/RE.15.04.00.00
bc19d96df3a95ae82368ac2083dc1cb77b39a2e9 commit refs/remotes/tags/RE.15.05.00.00
9cdf10ed94bcd5f88f121cb7977da79551918a7f commit refs/remotes/tags/RE.15.11.00.00
3d51a5ca903965b6043744c4995b3c17268c516b commit refs/remotes/tags/RE.16.03.00.00
83e65bbc68435b5622691acbaeba7e575bed08e4 commit refs/remotes/tags/RE.16.04.00.00
281e7aab7adc0d73fc678a39524cd8b64130fdfa commit refs/remotes/tags/RE.16.05.00.00
...
...
0cbf2d48633b5c8d691bf4b93208f02de0cd94fa commit refs/remotes/tags/RE.17.11.00.00
b57de4c3bc4caf4c77f2deb5eb10121193d39122 commit refs/remotes/tags/RE.17.11.10.00
1be3ba34cc0c0f556f972c6407605b560ad32f57 commit refs/remotes/tags/RE.18.01.00.00
56199738b9b4c523c7fc5daf00a3b7bd111f34f7 commit refs/remotes/tags/RE.18.02.00.00_IRIS-MIG
436823909e35cc78813042e1a2181048628e006d commit refs/remotes/tags/RE.18.03.00.00
f4edf4871858f180de3bae7c6dd04d1281e7a0f0 commit refs/remotes/tags/RE.18.03.00.00_ROLLBACK
4e38260f293ceb77281f0f87bd5816b48d0df174 commit refs/remotes/tags/RE.18.04.00.00
fcd58a4f0abf1b8dbb7d9edc846a831b964b09e4 commit refs/remotes/tags/RE.18.05.00.00
4e8936901052fd84804c7587cdb9c21ab980fc0e commit refs/remotes/tags/RE.18.06.00.00
18d443117221769ebccd42a1b22b06e039984c81 commit refs/remotes/tags/RE.18.08.00.00
8bfcb5f9c0b8d27f84e00ed5a2c4574cf726b357 commit refs/remotes/tags/RE18.06.00.00
6bb64c124aa47361c1fb951e6f6132ca09900b3f commit refs/remotes/tags/backup
b84d777d172d56bb43a18f9216cdfd48715cc76f commit refs/remotes/tags/backup@15657
a071ef00e51484338d1d8ee378f63a891d5e327b commit refs/remotes/tags/mod-security-2.2.7-test
5b0bd14307822551d65f1eabf06a229ac80cb0f2 commit refs/remotes/tags/mod-security2.2.7-testing
80b983c042b9ce5ce4c4b79fe02f1e4dec4785c5 commit refs/remotes/tags/package
568bf833abe733ebed65a0f2274826745c1c20bd commit refs/remotes/tags/package@15657
67155be3306148cc726711ec69092af4eba10845 commit refs/remotes/tags/props
f14622fc103a2c6ad1836c8a5d747f13936f5f7a commit refs/remotes/tags/props@15657
2c44a37dd69f45c58aabca388266232cfbbf108a commit refs/remotes/tags/rp
720d43aba7666cd9727d049dc3e04bc9827e4523 commit refs/remotes/tags/rp@15657
6bb64c124aa47361c1fb951e6f6132ca09900b3f commit refs/remotes/tags/tmp
b84d777d172d56bb43a18f9216cdfd48715cc76f commit refs/remotes/tags/tmp@15657
12d372c97e17f10ec5daba08debaf3e0fa887356 commit refs/remotes/trunk
```

But when I check this folder I see only few tags in it

```
$> ls -a .git/refs/remotes/tags/
.   RE.17.08.00.00  RE.17.11.10.00  RE.18.01.00.01  RE.18.02.00.00_IRIS-MIG  RE.18.03.00.00_ROLLBACK  RE.18.05.00.00  RE18.06.00.00
..  RE.17.10.00.00  RE.18.01.00.00  RE.18.02.00.00  RE.18.03.00.00           RE.18.04.00.00           RE.18.06.00.00  RE.18.08.00.00
```

Can some one tell me  why is there this difference?

**UPDATE**

I added this tags to my git and then did `git push --tag`

```
$> git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/remotes/tags | egrep "RE*" | cut -d / -f 4- | while read ref; do git tag -a "$ref" -m "$ref"; done
$> git tag
RE.12.04.00.00
RE.12.05.00.00
RE.12.06.00.00
RE.12.07.00.00
...
...
RE.18.02.00.00
RE.18.02.00.00_IRIS-MIG
RE.18.03.00.00
RE.18.03.00.00_ROLLBACK
RE.18.04.00.00
RE.18.05.00.00
RE.18.06.00.00
RE.18.08.00.00
RE18.06.00.00
```

Then in my git repository I have following:

[image][image]

As you can see all tags are related to the last commit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refs (such as tags) can be stored as individual files in `.git/refs/**`, or they can be stored as "packed references" in the single file `.git/packed-refs

---

*UpdatE* - question was edited to add some information about trying to add *tags* based on the `RE*` refs.  At this point it appears you're *really* asking how to create tags for each of these refs; please state your actual question clearly instead of making us guess what you want to know.

So: a tag is a ref that points to some object in the database, and that happens to be placed in the `refs/tags/` namespace.  By convention refs in this namespace should not "move around" (much if at all) and they become "names" for the objects they point to.

The `git tag` command takes, as an argument, the ID of - or an expression that resolves to - the object to which the ref should point.  You didn't give that argument, so it went with the default - which is `HEAD` (the commit that's checked out right now).

(Because of the order of arguments you used, it may not seem obvious that you omitted the target.  But what you gave was a `-a` option, then a tag name, then a `-m` option with an annotation matching the tag name.)

Instead of

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/remotes/tags | egrep "RE*" | cut -d / -f 4- | while read ref; do git tag -a "$ref" -m "$ref"; done
```

you could try

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/remotes/tags | egrep "RE*" | cut -d / -f 4- | while read ref; do git tag -a -m "$ref" "$ref" "refs/remotes/tags/$ref"; done
```

(Note that because you're creating an annotated tag, the ref will actually point to a new `TAG` object, which in turn will point to the correct commit.  This is normal, but be aware that the ref won't appear to point to the ID you might expect.)

Comment: Interesting, but how can I convert this refs to real git tags? I tried something like `git for-each-ref while read ref do git tag -a $ref; done` but then I get very strange tags that are not tied to commits

Comment: Comments aren't a great place for follow-up questions, as the information gets lost.  Please make sure your question encompasses the information you're seeking.  I see that you have updated the question with some follow-up (which I would also generally discourage, as existing answers to ever-changing questions become confusing when people in the future are searching for information).  I will update my answer to correspond to the current form of the question, but should you continue to find more related questions, I suggest researching them and then, if appropriate, posting new questions

Comment: Agree. I didn't found information about it, but I'll create new question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the updated Answer. Following your suggestion I added additional `"$ref"` to my command and then I got errors for all refs: `fatal: Failed to resolve 'RE18.06.00.00' as a valid ref.` Note `RE18.06.00.00` is different for each error

Comment: Oh. right.  The extra `$ref` should actually be `refs/remotes/tags/$ref`.  Edited above, and while I'm at it this time I also re-ordered the options to be a bit more intuitive.  (As originally written, it looks as though the first `$ref` were an argument to the `-a` option, but `-a` doesn't take an argument.)